# DataGridView System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, exception, datagridview

Why do I get this error when I want to edit a row of the database?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: And also, please do not post code as image. Post it as text and use the editors code formatting function.

Comment: ... yeah, and i guess, that your `Cell[0]` does not have a `Value`. Calling `ToString` on NULL throws a NullRef

Comment: To your _specific_ datagridview null ref, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442528/3585500).